# PTVS - general IntelliSense problems - no error highlighting, no recognition of modules from other projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, visual-studio-debugging, ptvs

I have used PTVS for two years now, and I remember (am I going crazy?) that PTVS always highlighted errors when working on a .py file in Visual Studio.

As of ~ Oct 10th (possible connected with v15.4 of VS2017), there have been issues with PTVS. In my frustration, I have completely reinstalled windows and wiped the entire computer clean. After installing drivers, I installed VS using the Visual Studio 2017 Community installer with the following options:

[image]

I then open Visual Studio, create a new empty python project, and type some garbage. No. Error. Correcting.

[image]

Am I going mad?

My python environment autocompletion / intellisense database is refreshed, by the way.

[image]

Meanwhile, the "View->Error List" window shows errors, even though they aren't highlighted.
[image]

Uninstalled the "Python native development tools" extension, still does not work. Installed with bare minimum python options (python language support, python 3.6, templates). Doesn't work.

Not sure if this is related (it probably is), Intellisense fails to recognize modules from other projects using any method. This was fine a week ago: (note green squiggles are Intellisense "Cannot resolve" errors)
[image]

Comment: The issue is about the squiggles, not the intellisense. Please check https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/writing-code-in-the-code-and-text-editor and we can know it and the intellisense is when you type ‘imp’ and you will find the list members like ‘import’ and others that ready for you to select. Please open a Python Interactive Window to see if Intellisense works there or not. Or choose the Python 3.6 (64-bit) as the environment to test it. In my side, the Error and Warning Marks works fine https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKlyPZWjJBMRgghNXf, upgrade VS 2017 to the latest one.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Thanks for the reply. I am using the latest release of Visual 2017 because I just installed it today. I also reinstalled the operating system and wiped the system clean. Code Auto-Completion works, yes. That feature is fine. Squiggles and recognizing modules from other projects is broken currently, for me at least. Not sure why my case would be exceptional, anyone who starts with fresh Windows and installs fresh Visual Studio with python options selected should experience the same thing. I wonder if you are using an older, not-broken version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue as  yours, but it could show the Red color in VS2015.

[image]

For this issue, I help you report this issue to the developer community site:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/132688/ptvs-general-intellisense-problems-no-error-highli.html

You could add your comment there.

For the second issue, about the module reference. Not the real Python team members, but maybe you could find a way here:

[How to import functions from other projects in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509192/how-to-import-functions-from-other-projects-in-python)

One thread for one issue, maybe you could start a new python issue for it.

Comment: Re: Importing from other projects - I already know how to get Intellisense to scrape modules from other projects or any system path. You simply add the path to the project's Search Paths, and Intellisense will scrape that directory upon DB refresh. I have used PTVS for two years, and know this feature is now broken as of 15.4. Also, Thanks for showing 2015 and 2017 side-by-side, it really clearly shows what's wrong. +1

Comment: @OrangeSherbet, You are welcome, and glad to know that you have resolved one issue. For the feedback, you could also vote and add your comment there, the product team would share the update there. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that fixed on 31 October 2017 with Update 15.4.2

[Source](http://visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in VS 2017 15.4, and [apparently](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/131724/python-tools-for-vs-broken-since-update-154.html) it will be fixed upon next release. For anyone experiencing these issues, VS 2015's Python Tools work if you need any of these functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the latest information about this issue. You could also mark helpful reply as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue.