# How to deal with one common lib folder for multiple projects in Python

Tags: python, svn, directory-structure

I have one Python library folder, with sub-folders and  .py files within, for various custom classes and functions. Further, I have multiple distinct Python projects, living somewhere else on my file system, which need to include and make use of that common library folder.

Moreover, I need to work with SVN. Both the common library folder and all the projects should live in their own SVN repo.

What is the "best", i.e. pythonic way of dealing with such a setup? For now, working under Linux, I just symlinked from my Python projects to that common library folder. However, that does not feel right, and in future I might want to port all that to Windows machines as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a note: symlinks are a thing in (modern) windows too.

Comment: I don't think there is a best way to deal with it, just different approach such as monorepo or a shared API

Comment: @S.C.A That might be, but maybe there is something like a "best practice" approach. I don't know any of them, so I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Try to refer this article (resolving similar task as like you): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509192/how-to-import-functions-from-other-projects-in-python

Comment: [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) is **The Ultimate Answer (tm)**