# How to import a package that use absolute import in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, volatility

I'm trying to import [volatility3](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility3) into my python project/script, so that I don't have to use os.system since volatility3 is already made in python3.

I'm wondering how can I import all the functions/modules of said project ? The functions I'm interested in are located in volatility3/volatility/framework
I tried simply putting:

```
>>> import volatility3.volatility.framework
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/volatility3/volatility/framework/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from volatility.framework import constants, interfaces
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'volatility'
```

My guess is I have to modify sys.path or one of the **path** variables but this does not seem to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here would be to properly install volatility with pip3, from your already exiting repository folder:

```
$ pip3 install /home/volatility3
```

or directly from pipy (not tested):

```
$ pip3 install volatility3
```

then you should be able to import the from `volatility` package directly:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import volatility.framework
>>> volatility.framework
<module 'volatility.framework' from '/home/bruno/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/volatility/framework/__init__.py'>
>>>
```

Comment: Yes thank you. That's what I was looking for.
Actually, I found the same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509192/how-to-import-functions-from-other-projects-in-python
I didn't know how to phrase my problem. Also it seems volatility3 is available from pip3 without having to clone the volatility repo
Thanks again

Comment: @Win well yes of course if the package is on pipy (I didn't bothered looking it up since you already had a local repo clone). Answer edited.