# Django importing models between multiple db & multiple project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

My setup include django 3.0 , my directory structure is:

```
/webapp/
      api_1/app1/models.py
      
      api_2/app1/models.py
```

The api_1 used multiple db which are configured by db routing. i want to import the api_2.app1.ModelA in my api_1.views.
i have tried to add the sys.path.append('/webapp/api_2') in api_2.wsgi, add the api_2.app1 in the INSTALLED_APPS of api_1 but still getting error of `cannot found Module api_2`. i have also tried reverse of it but cannot import that also.

Comment: how does your regular import statment look like? `from api_2.app1.models import *`? I am a bit confused, are those two different django apps or django projects with own settings file etc?

Comment: @hansTheFranz yes these are two different projects with their own settings. my import statement looks like exactly you have defined

Comment: You can import classes from other projects, in the end they are all python classes and can be used in other python projects.have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509192/how-to-import-functions-from-other-projects-in-python . If you want to do this in a production enviroment I would sugest to look into micro services and how to exchange data between two servers via restapi or whatever...